# Netbeans GlassFish Server 6, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false error on Mac

Tags: netbeans, server, glassfish

After deploying my javaee application from the Apache Netbeans 12.4 console, I get the the below error on the output pane.

*GlassFish Server 6, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false*

This error shows even after the output *"GlassFish server is running"* was displayed earlier in the deployment messages.

I have checked the GlassFish folder in my mac and there are no error logs showing. Attempting to start GlassFish in debug mode gives the same issue.

Any advices on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I figured that this issue was as a result of GlassFish not having administrative privileges to make changes to my filesystem.

All I needed to do was to start up GlassFish as an admin.

Usually, GlassFish is installed on the below path of your Mac.
***/Users/YourUsername/GlassFish_Server***

The below are the steps to achieve that.

1. Navigate to the bin folder of your GlassFish Server. 
   ***/Users/YourUsername/GlassFish_Server/bin***
2. Run the **asadmin** command using the below command. 
   ***./asadmin***
3. Then in the console that opens, type the below command.
   ***start-domain***

After a few seconds, the GlassFish server is now running. You can test this on your browser at the default admin port using **localhost:4848** or http port of **localhost:8080**

To stop GlassFish, follow the same steps above, however execute the ***"stop-domain"*** command for step 3.

I hope it reduces some stress for someone.